# How to tackle a homework prgram that reads three sides for a triangle and computes the area if the input is valid?

Tags: java, netbeans

Here is my task:

> Create a class named MyTriangle that contains the following two methods:
>
> ```
> /** Return true if the sum of any two sides is * greater than the third side. */
> public static boolean isValid (double side1, double side2, double side3)
>
> /** Return the area of the triangle. */ 
> public static double area (double side1, double side2, double side3)
> ```
>
> Write a test program that reads three sides for a triangle and computes the area if the input is valid. Otherwise, it displays that the input is invalid.

Attempt below: Question: I cannot figure this out and the constantly rereading the chapter isn't breaking through any walls. The **issue** is commented in the code below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NewClass1 {   

double area;
double side1, side2, side3;
double x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3;

public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter two integers for side 1:");
        double x1 = input.nextDouble();
        double y1 = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Enter two integers for side 2:");
        double x2 = input.nextDouble();
        double y2 = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Enter two integers for side 3:");
        double x3 = input.nextDouble();
        double y3 = input.nextDouble();

        boolean isValid = true;

            if (isValid) {
                System.out.println("Input is invalid");
            }
                else
                    area(side1, side2, side3); //Using area does not work and I don't know how to remedy this. I've read the chapter over and over... I cannot get it to work.

    }

    public static double area(double side1, double side2, double side3) {
        double x1 = 0;
        double x2 = 0;
        double y1 = 0;
        double y2 = 0;
        double x3 = 0;
        double y3 = 0; 

            side1 = Math.pow(Math.pow(x2 - x1, 2) + Math.pow(y2 - y1, 2), 0.5);
            side2 = Math.pow(Math.pow(x3 - x1, 2) + Math.pow(y3 - y1, 2), 0.5);
            side3 = Math.pow(Math.pow(x3 - x2, 2) + Math.pow(y3 - y2, 2), 0.5);

            //Calculates the sides/angles using Heron's formula
            double s = (side1 + side2 + side3)/2;
            double area = Math.pow(s * (s - side1) * (s - side2) * (s - side3), 0.5);

            return (area);
    } 

    public static boolean isValid(double side1, double side2, double side3) {

        return (((side1 + side2) > side3) && ((side1 + side3) > side2) && ((side2 + side3) > side1));
    }
}
```

Reviewing the code, can someone please explain what it is that I'm doing wrong, and explain a possible remedy. Everything is there, I simply cannot connect the dots.

Revision--Code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NewClass1 {   

    public static void main(String[] args) {

            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.print("Enter side 1: ");
            double side1 = input.nextDouble();

            System.out.print("Enter side 2: ");
            double side2 = input.nextDouble();

            System.out.print("Enter side 3: ");
            double side3 = input.nextDouble();

            double a = area(side1, side2, side3);
            boolean isV = isValid(side1, side2, side3);

                    if (isV)
                        System.out.println("Inout is Invalid");
                    else
                        System.out.println("Area is: " + a);
        }

    public static boolean isValid(double side1, double side2, double side3) {

         return (((side1 + side2) > side3) && ((side1 + side3) > side2) && ((side2 + side3) > side1));
    }

    public static double area(double side1, double side2, double side3) {

                //Calculates the sides/angles using Heron's formula
        double s = (side1 + side2 + side3)/2;
        double theArea = Math.pow(s * (s - side1) * (s - side2) * (s - side3), 0.5);

            return (theArea);
    } 
}
```

I keep getting `NaN` as the answer for the area. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't have time to write much now, but the central problem is that x1, y1, etc. never get to the `area` method. The variables declared in the `area` method and the ones in the `main` method shadow the variables declared as instance variables. They are separate variables, though they happen to have the same names. You need to pass the coordinates into the method.

Comment: You set a `boolean isValid` to `true`. You don't set it to anything else. You never call your `isValid()` method. You also seem to print "Input is invalid" when `isValid` is `true`, which doesn't really make sense.

Comment: what do you mean by call?

Comment: so why doesn't it make sense?

Comment: I don't understand the coordination portion of this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you write the following:
if the input is valid, show error message. Otherwise (else) compute area.
You should just swap your if and else parts! Your program never calls the area() method if you are calling it with points for a valid triangle.
Moreover, you never call the isValid() method. You assign true to the variable, and then check it in the next line, but the method that actually checks it has never been called.

ALSO you need side variables for isValid(), but you only compute them in the area() method. You should compute them right after you get the points.

Comment: Does the program call the `isValid` method? This answer is far from complete.

Comment: I am beyond lost on the 'call' portion of this. Had a similar issue with another program and failed to understand it completely...

Comment: To call a method is basically to write a statement which involves the name of the method.
So, for example, you write:
    double a = area(2, 3, 5);
In this statement you called a method area(). It means that the program is going to find an implementation of that method (where you explained how to find an area given three sides), go through it line by line (because obviously it doesn't just know by default what area() does) and execute it, and return the result.

Comment: That's understandable. I Don't know why everyone else refuses to provide this level of explanation. Thank you!

Comment: No problem! I hope you can finish this now. Remember, a method only does what it is designed to do. Don't calculate sides in area() if you don't need that; just calculate the area. This will make your program more simple and readable.

Comment: Ugh. I had a similar question posted on here that actually didn't answer anything for me. I can't figure out the steps and I can't request an answer, because I'll get looked down on. I'm a visual learner. visuals need to accompany a thorough explanation or vice versa or I'm not getting it, period. I can only learn by example, not reading something 100 times over. Do you know of a site for visual learners or people like-minded?

Comment: Nope, I don't, to be fair. But you should know that programming is not learning! You gain absolutely nothing from memorizing things in programming. You just have to understand them. 
There is a book called "How to think like a programmer", find it and read it. (Might be on-line somewhere) The way you think it critical here, not learning things.

Comment: I looked up the book and watched some videos the author posted about developing the thought process--it is a process. It's pretty straightforward. I was able to solve the problem. Question: Calling the method, a method that has instructions which produces a result. Calling a method requests the results, OR for a process to start work following a set of instructions to produce a result?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are asking completely, but I think it's the second. An example: you want to cook me a cake. You have a recipe for it. So, when I tell you to cook_a_cake() (i.e. I call the method) I expect you to grab the recipe, follow the steps and produce a result - a cake that we can eat =). Have I answered your question?

P.S So if after that I call the method again, you will cook me another cake, you can't just give me the same one even if we haven't eaten it yet.

Comment: Hah. Yes, that answers my question. Thank you, again.

Comment: Never mind. I don't have the answer... I don't understand what is needed to complete it. Thanks for the explanations though.

Answer (score 2):

You are just declaring a variable called "isValid" and setting it equal to true.  You need to instead calculate the length of the sides before you check if the input is valid.  Then you call the isValid **function** by calling

`isValid(side1, side2, side3);`

Answer (score 2):

When you call the area method (which you are not calling per @mashaned 's answer)

```
area(side1, side2, side3);
```

You are calling it with variables that have only been initialized and not set.
side1, side2, and side3 do not have a value when you call area.

You should either create a class for side variables so that you can pass in the x and y values like this:

```
area(new Side(x1, y1), new Side(x2, y2), new Side(x3, y3));
```

Or

You should change the area method to accept `x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3` instead of sides since you are computing sides in the area method like:

```
public static double area(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, double x3, double y3) {
```

Additionally, you are not doing anything with the area returned by the area method when you call it.
I suggest something like:

```
System.out.println("Area " + String.valueOf([INSERT VERSION OF AREA METHOD CALL OF YOUR CHOICE]));
```

The first answer is also right about the `isValid` variable. You are not using the `isValid()` method for validation.

You should use it in similar fashion to area in terms of what is passed in.

An example class (roughly done) might be like the following:

```
public class Side(){
        double x = 0;
        double y = 0;

        public Side(double x, double y){
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        public double getX(){
            return this.x;
        }

        public double getY(){
            return this.y;
        }

        public void setX(double x){
            this.x = x;
        }

        public void setY(double y){
            this.y = y;
        }
    }
```

You may want to consider adding this method and removing the similar code from your area method:

```
public void computeSides(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, double x3, double y3){
        side1 = Math.pow(Math.pow(x2 - x1, 2) + Math.pow(y2 - y1, 2), 0.5);
        side2 = Math.pow(Math.pow(x3 - x1, 2) + Math.pow(y3 - y1, 2), 0.5);
        side3 = Math.pow(Math.pow(x3 - x2, 2) + Math.pow(y3 - y2, 2), 0.5);
    }
```

Then when you go to call isValid() or area() you just make sure you call computeSides() first and then the side variables will have values and both should work.

Answer (score -1):

‏Write a method computeArea that takes three sides of a triangle and returns the area of that triangle (assume the sides are valid) Write a main method to read the sides of two triangles, compute their areas (using the computeArea method), and print the sides of the triangle with larger area. run:

Enter the sides for the triangle: 4 6 9

Enter the sides for the triangle: 3 9 8

the triangle with largest area has the folowing sides:

side1: 3.0, Side2: 9.0, and side3: 8.0