# How to tackle a homework prgram that reads three sides for a triangle and computes the area if the input is valid? (2)

Tags: java, netbeans

This is a re-ask of the following question: [How to tackle a homework prgram that reads three sides for a triangle and computes the area if the input is valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28953391/homework-write-a-prgram-that-reads-three-sides-for-a-triangle-and-computes-the)

Here is the task again:

> Create a class named MyTriangle that contains the following two methods:
>
> ```
> /** Return true if the sum of any two sides is * greater than the third side. */
> public static boolean isValid (double side1, double side2, double side3)
>
> /** Return the area of the triangle. */ 
> public static double area (double side1, double side2, double side3)
> ```
>
> Write a test program that reads three sides for a triangle and computes the area if the input is valid. Otherwise, it displays that the input is invalid.

Attempt below: Question: I cannot figure this out and the constantly rereading the chapter isn't breaking through any walls. The **issue** is commented in the code below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NewClass1 {   

double area;
double side1, side2, side3;
double x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3;

public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter two integers for side 1:");
        double x1 = input.nextDouble();
        double y1 = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Enter two integers for side 2:");
        double x2 = input.nextDouble();
        double y2 = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Enter two integers for side 3:");
        double x3 = input.nextDouble();
        double y3 = input.nextDouble();

        boolean isValid = true;

            if (isValid) {
                System.out.println("Input is invalid");
            }
                else
                    area(side1, side2, side3); //Using area does not work and I don't know how to remedy this. I've read the chapter over and over... I cannot get it to work.

    }

    public static double area(double side1, double side2, double side3) {
        double x1 = 0;
        double x2 = 0;
        double y1 = 0;
        double y2 = 0;
        double x3 = 0;
        double y3 = 0; 

            side1 = Math.pow(Math.pow(x2 - x1, 2) + Math.pow(y2 - y1, 2), 0.5);
            side2 = Math.pow(Math.pow(x3 - x1, 2) + Math.pow(y3 - y1, 2), 0.5);
            side3 = Math.pow(Math.pow(x3 - x2, 2) + Math.pow(y3 - y2, 2), 0.5);

            //Calculates the sides/angles using Heron's formula
            double s = (side1 + side2 + side3)/2;
            double area = Math.pow(s * (s - side1) * (s - side2) * (s - side3), 0.5);

            return (area);
    } 

    public static boolean isValid(double side1, double side2, double side3) {

        return (((side1 + side2) > side3) && ((side1 + side3) > side2) && ((side2 + side3) > side1));
    }
}
```

Reviewing the code, can someone please explain what it is that I'm doing wrong, and explain a possible remedy. Everything is there, I simply cannot connect the dots. Thank you.

**Revised Code**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NewClass1 {   

    public static void main(String[] args) {

            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.print("Enter side 1: ");
            double side1 = input.nextDouble();

            System.out.print("Enter side 2: ");
            double side2 = input.nextDouble();

            System.out.print("Enter side 3: ");
            double side3 = input.nextDouble();

            double a = area(side1, side2, side3);
            boolean isV = isValid(side1, side2, side3);

                    if (isV)
                        System.out.println("Inout is Invalid");
                    else
                        System.out.println("Area is: " + a);
        }

    public static boolean isValid(double side1, double side2, double side3) {

         return (((side1 + side2) > side3) && ((side1 + side3) > side2) && ((side2 + side3) > side1));
    }

    public static double area(double side1, double side2, double side3) {

                //Calculates the sides/angles using Heron's formula
        double s = (side1 + side2 + side3)/2;
        double theArea = Math.pow(s * (s - side1) * (s - side2) * (s - side3), 0.5);

            return (theArea);
    } 
}
```

I keep getting `NaN` as the answer for the area. What am I doing wrong?

I've been at this for over 7 hours simply because I don't understand the possible problems there are. I'm 2 months into this CompSci course.

Comment: NaN is because `(s * (s - side1) * (s - side2) * (s - side3)` is negative (when Java tries to take square root of negatives, it throws NaN).

Comment: Your revised code works for me, except for one thing: `if (isV)` should be `if (!isV)`. What kinds of numbers are you inputting?

Comment: What inputs give you NaN....if you got NaN shouldn't you at least tell us what you used to get it?

Comment: Show us your sample inputs.  I try to  ` double a = area(11.1, 22.2, 33.3);
            boolean isV = isValid(11.1, 22.2, 33.3);` to hard code the inputs. Output i get is 8,. @Chris RedFieldea

Comment: Any number(s) of any length, with/out a decimal place.

Comment: @Chris, 11.1/22.2/33.3 is _not_ a triangle. It's a straight line of length 33.3.

Comment: Yeah, looking at it some more, William Gaul has it right. Your incorrect boolean is making it so that values going into area() are invalid, thus throwing NaN error. Swap it around and you should be fine.

Comment: Still NaN--with 1/2/6 with the switched Boolean.

Comment: @Chris, I say again, `1/2/6` is _not_ a triangle. _Each_ of the pairs must have a sum greater than the other side. Think about it: if you "flatten the `1/2` lines, there's _no_ way it could reach from one end of the `6` line to the other end, because they combine  to make only a `3`.

Comment: (Pythagorean triple) It would have helped to have been given this info by the instructor because I didn't know it was 3/4/5.

Comment: Thank you all who responded so swiftly and collectively. This helped more than you all know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method `isValid` returns true if the triangle is valid yet you're assuming the opposite:

```
double a = area(side1, side2, side3);
boolean isV = isValid(side1, side2, side3);
if (isV)
    System.out.println("Inout is Invalid");
```

This is further supported by your input data (in a comment) of sides `11.1`, `22.2` and `33.3`. That's *not* a triangle, it's a series of overlapping line segments.

If you type in the perfectly valid `3/4/5` triangle, you'll get an error stating that it's not a triangle.

So, simply change the code above to be something like (there's no point calling `area` on invalid data):

```
if (! isValid(side1, side2, side3))
    System.out.println("Inout is Invalid");
else
    System.out.println("Area is " + area(side1, side2, side3));
```

Making those changes:

```
package test2;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test2 {   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter three sides, separated by spaces: ");
        double s1 = input.nextDouble();
        double s2 = input.nextDouble();
        double s3 = input.nextDouble();
        if (isValid(s1, s2, s3))
            System.out.println("Area is: " + area(s1, s2, s3));
        else
            System.out.println("Input is Invalid");
    }

    public static boolean isValid(double s1, double s2, double s3) {
         return ((s1 + s2 > s3) && (s1 + s3 > s2) && (s2 + s3 > s1));
    }

    public static double area(double s1, double s2, double s3) {
        double s = (s1 + s2 + s3) / 2;
        double theArea = Math.pow(s * (s - s1) * (s - s2) * (s - s3), 0.5);
        return theArea;
    } 
}
```

and entering a *valid* triangle, like `3/4/5` or `5/5/8` gives you the correct results:

```
Enter three sides, separated by spaces: 3 4 5
Area is: 6.0

Enter three sides, separated by spaces: 5 5 8
Area is: 12.0
```

Comment: `!` stands for 'not equal', yes? I'm trying to work this out in my head. If it's not equal wouldn't `if` compute the area and `else` report the error?

Comment: Never mind. I'm completely ignoring the equation when I ask the question. Thank you for your reviewing my code!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

`if (isV)` should be `if (!isV)`. If the condition isn't correct, then you're *only* executing Heron's formula with potentially dangerous input that can possibly cause `s * (s - side1) * (s - side2) * (s - side3)` to be negative. Taking the square root of a negative number is undefined with Java primitive types.

Answer (score 1):

Use this .. Heron's formula

[image]

[image]

```
double sidesSvalue = (a + b + c)/2.0d;
double productofSides = (sidesSvalue  * (sidesSvalue -a) * (sidesSvalue -b) * (sidesSvalue -c));
double Area= Math.sqrt(productofSides );
return Area;
```

whenever your values are invalid they are going into the area please correct your conditional code you should use something like this

```
if(!isValid)
   print error message
else 
   calculate area
```

one last thing always try to use the same primitive type when using DMAS operations.

Comment: `! isValid` I understand now. DMAS operations? Don't think I'm far enough in the chapter to know what they are. Sorry.

Comment: DMAS(Division,Multiplication,Addition,Subtraction). :)

Comment: Ah. I was unfamiliar with the acronym. I thought it was some special topic in the Java universe.